# If I return an object is it a reference or not?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm pretty new to the world of software but have read and experience that when you have an object like:

```
const obj1 = {key1: "val1", key2: "val2"};

// and then do this =>
const obj2 = obj1;
// obj2 isn't a new object but a reference to object 1

// which you can demonstrate with 
console.log(obj1);
obj2.key1 = "value3";
console.log(obj1);
// now key1 of object 1 has changed
```

But I'm kind of wondering what happens in the following situation.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

function getUrlParams(_urlParams) {
    let retObj = new Object();

    _urlParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
        retObj[key] = value;
    });

    return retObj;
}

const urlArgs = getUrlParams(urlParams);
```

I couldn't really figure out a way to test if urlArgs is now a reference to retObj or not. I doubt it is since retObj was defined inside of the function and should no longer exist when the function is done. But with what I know of javascript I'm not really sure.

After reading some comments is there a way to test if

```
urlArgs === retObj;
// If urlArgs and retObj are both referencing the same object?
```

Comment: urlArgs is not a reference to retObj. However, urlArgs and retObj are both references to the same object.

Comment: But I feel like returning retObj is basically the same as saying `const urlArgs = retObj;` which would be the same as the first code block. Is that not the case?

Comment: The `retObj` variable goes out of scope when `getUrlParams()` returns, so can no longer be used. But the *value* of `retObj` is returned and assigned to `urlArgs`. That value is a reference to the dynamically allocated `Object`.

Comment: `const obj2 = obj1;` makes `obj2` a reference to whatever `obj1` is a reference to. It does not make `obj2` a reference to `obj1`. (If you do `obj1 = 42;` and then print `obj2`, then you'll see that `obj2` did not change to `42`.)

Answer (score 1):

There's some basic knowledge that you are missing, how references work.

**Two objects**

For example: `console.log({ age: 42 } === { age: 42});` => return `false`.

Note that in order to compare references of objects you should use `===`.

The two object have the same values but they are not the same object in memory. In your example, you are coping all the properties of `urlParams`, both object will "look" the same, but will not be the exact same location in memory.

**Same object example:**

```
const person1 = { age: 42 }; // Creating a new object in memory, and pointing "person1" to it
const person2 = person1; // creating another point to the same object.
console.log(person1 === person3); // ==> returns true
```

Are you can see, when creating an object like this: `const person1 = { age: 42};` does 2 things, creating an object and a reference to it. on the next line `const person2 = person1;` only a new reference to the same memory location is created.

That's why, when changing the `age` of one of the references will be reflected in the other reference (same memory)

**primitives**

Another important thing to understand is that primitives (numbers, booleans, strings, symbol, and bigint) are **not** references.

```
const a = 42;
const b = a; // this is a COPY, not a reference
```

**Releasing the memory**

In Javascript all your variable are "alive" (In memory) as long as there's a reference to them. when you define a variable in a function, this variable is "alive" in the scope of the function. after this function execution is done, the variable is released.

In short, when all references are gone, the memory is released automatically. (this called garbage collection).

Comment: The question is asking if `urlArgs` (the value assigned to the return of the function call `getUrlParams(...)`) is the same reference to that of the object created inside the function (`retObj`), it isn't asking about if `urlParams` object is the same as `retObj`

Comment: Is the reference retObj gone after the function is done?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario retObj is more class like in that it is an Object making factory. Each time you pass in parameters you are building a completely different object with you retObj factory and after the function is done running retObj is removed from memory.

If you moved retObj outside of the getUrlParams function like so

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

let retObj = new Object();

function getUrlParams(_urlParams) {

    _urlParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
        retObj[key] = value;
    });

    return retObj;
}

const urlArgs = getUrlParams(urlParams);
```

you could then play around with it but at this point it would be on the global level and any changes to the data would propagate up/down since retObj would have a dedicated space in memory making urlArg a reference to retObj.